# Le yod indu en français populaire et autres particularités du français québecois au subjonctif présent du verbe être?

Tags: prononciation, oral, québec, phonétique, linguistique

> **Les verbes qui ont un yod [j]** à certaines formes connaissent
>   l'alternance [...]  un *y* quand le [j] est présent, un *i* sinon.
>   [...] La langue populaire tend à introduire un yod indu à la finale
>   [...].
>
> Le sergot répondit avec une austère douceur : / — Que ce SOYE pour une
>   idée ou pour autre chose, ce n'était pas à dire (France).
>
> [ Le bon usage, Grevisse et Goosse, DeBoeck, 14­<sup>e</sup> § 793. ]

En français parlé [au Québec](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois) on entend ça assez souvent il me semble. En y pensant bien j'ai déjà entendu l'oral au subjonctif présent du verbe *être* (mais je les perçois différemment, s'éloignant de plus en plus d'une norme) :

> Qu'il/elle soit, *soye, sweille, seille*.

S'agit-il dans tous les cas d'un exemple de yod indu ; comment décrirait-on les autres différences de prononciation évoquées ; à quelle(s) [caractéristique(s)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prononciation_du_fran%C3%A7ais_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois) du français (du Québec) se rattacheraient ces variantes ; retrouve-t-on toujours la prononciation *soye* en français métropolitain populaire, avec ce temps (subjonctif présent) et ce verbe (*être*) ?

Answer (score 3):

La prononciation /swaj/ pour /swa/ s'explique, je crois, par les formes *soyons* /**swaj**ɔ̃/ et *soyez* /**swaj**e/ qui fournissent un radical en /swaj/ ou /swɛj/ pour le français québécois, radical qui est utilisé par analogie pour les autres personnes.

La forme *seille*, prononcée /sɛj/ j'imagine, est intéressante en ce qu'elle semble prolonger la concurrence entre deux formes du subjonctif présent du verbe *être* ayant longtemps coexisté en français de France.  On a l'évolution suivante du subjonctif présent d'*être* :

- latin classique : sĭm - sīs - sĭt - sīmus - sītis - sĭnt
- roman commun : sĭam/sēam - sĭas/sēas - sĭat/sēat - sĭamus/sēamus - sĭatis/sēatis - sĭant/sēant
- ancien français : seie/soie - seies/soies - sei(e)t/soit - seiens/soions - seiez/soiez - seient/soient
- français moderne : sois - sois - soit - soyons - soyez - soient

ĭ représente un i bref et ī un i long.

A l'époque classique (XVIIe siècle), on hésite pour *soit*, entre la prononciation /swɛ/ et /sɛ/.

Vaugelas préfère /sɛ/.  Il dit dans ses *Remarques* 98 et 99 :

« …Une infinité de gens disent *mains* /mɛ̃/, pour dire *moins* /mwɛ̃/, et par conséquent *néanmains* pour *néanmoins*, *je dais*, *tu dais*, *il dait*, pour dire, *je dois*, *tu dois*, *il doit*, ce qui est insupportable. »

Il donne ensuite quelques règles pour la prononciation de oi, /wɛ/ (selon la prononciation du temps remplacée depuis par /wa/ en France) ou /ɛ/.

« Premièrement, dans tous les monosyllabes on doit prononcer *oi* /wɛ/ et non *ai* /ɛ/, comme *loi*, *bois*, *dois*, *quoi*, *moi*, *toi*, *soi*, *moi*, *fois*, et tous les autres, dont le nombre est grand.  Il y en a fort peu d'exceptés, comme *froid*, *crois*, *droit*, ***soient***, ***soit*** que l'on prononce en *ai*, *fraid*, *crais*, *drait*, ***saient***, ***sait***, si ce n'est quand on dit *soit* pour approuver quelque chose, car alors il faut dire *soit* /swɛ/, et non pas *sait* /sɛ/ (…). »

C'est ce dernier *Soit!* qu'on prononce maintenant /swat/.

Bruneau et Brunot dans leur *Précis de grammaire historique de la langue française* ajoutent à propos de *soit* /sɛ/ :

« C'est une vieille prononciation distinguée et courtisane du XVIe siècle; Du Bellay (*Regrets*, X, v. 12-13) faisait déjà rimer *Français* et *Que je sois*; cette rime reste excellente pendant toute l'époque classique.  La prononciation /swɛ/ subsistait néanmoins, évoluant en /swa/.  En 1805, Domerque exige /swa/ "au nom de l'usage et de la raison".  Il ajoute toutefois : "Des professeurs distingués prononcent à Paris : que je /sɛ/". »

Je serais curieux de savoir quel est le statut de *seille* /sɛj/ par rapport à *sweille* /swɛj/ au Québec.  *Seille* fait-il partie de la langue standard, si ce n'est pas le cas, comment est-il perçu?

Comment: Oui c'est _seille_ comme dans Marseille. Je pense que je le perçois comme moins soigné que _soye_ mais je ne sais pas si c'est si différent de _sweille_. Je suis pas mal certain d'autre part que dire _seille_ n'est pas ce qui est de plus courant au Québec. Quand je lis un texte qui contient le subjonctif il ne me vient pas à l'esprit de dire autrement que swa, c'est à l'oral que ça se manifeste et _soye_ et _sweille_ sont assez similaires finalement. Le deuxième me demande peut-être plus d'effort à prononcer et est plus loin de ma norme de prononciation personnelle (sud-ouest Qc).